# React not executing block of switch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a product component that renders n number of sections. The code in the product component:

```
let sections = this.state.product.sections.map((section, idx) => {
  return (
    <Section sectionType={section.id} section={section} />
  )
})

return (
  <div>
    {this.state.product.name}
    {sections}
  </div>
)
```

The code in the section component:

```
renderSection() {
 switch (this.props.sectionType) {
  case 'heroImage':
    return (
      <img src={image.url} />
    )
  case 'doublePane':
    this.props.section.items.map((item, idx) => {
      console.log(item.id);
      if (1 === 1) {
        return (
          <div>hi</div>
        )
      }
    })
  default:
    return (
      <div>hey there</div>
    )
}
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderSection()}
    </div>
)
}
```

I added the 1===1 line just to make sure it would execute, but the output of my code is still

1. the heroImage case properly executes
2. the console log of item.id happens (so we definitely enter the doublePane block), but the code inside of the 1===1 block does not execute.

Any idea what's happening here to not allow me to run the code inside of the 1===1? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your return is inside the `.map()` callback... nothing is being returned in the actual switch case

Comment: If the `console.log(item.id)` is executing then `return ( <div>hi</div> )` also executed. The problem is you are returning inside `.map()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of the mapping function, in addition to returning within the mapping function:

```
renderSection() {
  switch (this.props.sectionType) {
    case 'heroImage':
      return (
        <img src={image.url} />
      );
    case 'setOfTwo':
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.section.items.map((item, idx) => {
             console.log(item.id);
             return (
               <div>hi</div>
             );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <div>hey there</div>
      )
  }
}
```

Wrapping the return value in a `div` isn't necessarily required, but I prefer to return a consistent item (in this case a single JSX element) from functions.